# Map ConfigParser dictionary to a class constructor with correct value types

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, configparser

I have a config ini file which looks like below:

```
[user]
name=john
sex=male
age=19
income=2345.99
```

And I have a Python class called `User` with `__init__` constructor below:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name: str, sex: str, age: int, income: float):
        self.__name = name
        self.__sex = sex
        self.__age = age
        self.__income = income
```

When I use `ConfigParser` to read the ini file & pass the configparser dictionary to the `User` constructor, the values in the dictionary are string.

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('test.ini')
user = User(**config["user"])
```

`ConfigParser` has methods like `getfloat`, `getint`, `getboolean`. I could use those methods & get the correct data type for each parameter.

However, this would require me to pass each parameter to the `User` constructor. It can be troublesome whenever I need to add/remove parameter for the `User` constructor

Is there anyway to use `user = User(**config["user"])` in the constructor & configure `ConfigParser` to translate the value to correct data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This becomes trivial if you use something like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/):

```
import pydantic
import configparser


class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    sex: str
    age: int
    income: float


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
with open("config.ini") as fd:
    config.read_file(fd)

user = User(**config["user"])
```

At this point, the string values from the config file have been converted into the appropriate data types:

```
>>> type(user.income)
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: How do you do this dynamically on the User Class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Maybe you want to [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: Based on any dictionary from a config.ini file, create a Pydantic class